# gulp not concatenating to vendor.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, task-runner-explorer

I have installed the gulp-concat module and am trying to concatenate my libraries, however it does not seem to want to create the vendor.js file.  I am rather new to gulp.  At the top of my gulpfile I have

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gulpVendor = require('gulp-concat-vendor'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    tap = require('gulp-tap'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    widgetsTemplatesLoader = require('./tools/widgets-templates-loader');


var dirs = {
    content: './Content',
    tmp: './.tmp',
    templates: './Content/templates',
    bower: './bower_components'
};

dirs.templates = dirs.content + '/templates';
dirs.dist = dirs.content + '/dist';
dirs.app = dirs.content + '/app';
dirs.modules = dirs.app + '/modules';
dirs.fonts = dirs.content + '/fonts';
dirs.css = dirs.content + '/css';

var paths = {
    scripts: {
        app: [dirs.app + '/**/*.js',
            '!' + dirs.app + '/widgets/**/*.js'],

        vendor: [
            dirs.bower + '/lodash/lodash.js',
            dirs.bower + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            dirs.bower + '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            dirs.bower + '/jqueryui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',
            dirs.bower + '/Sortable/Sortable.js',
            // angular
            dirs.bower + '/angular/angular.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-dashboard-framework/dist/angular-dashboard-framework.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.js',

            dirs.bower + '/moment/moment.js',
            dirs.bower + '/ui-select/dist/select.js',
            dirs.bower + '/javascript-detect-element-resize/jquery.resize.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-gridster/dist/angular-gridster.min.js',
            dirs.bower + '/highcharts/highcharts.src.js',
            dirs.bower + '/ng-resize/dist/ng-resize.js',
            dirs.bower + '/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-daterangepicker/js/angular-daterangepicker.js',
            dirs.bower + '/showdown/compressed/Showdown.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-markdown-directive/markdown.js',
            dirs.bower + '/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.js'
        ]
    },
    widgets: dirs.app + '/widgets',
    less: [
        dirs.bower + '/angular-gridster/dist/angular-gridster.min.css',
        dirs.bower + '/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.css',
        dirs.bower + '/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
        dirs.bower + '/jqueryui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css',
        dirs.bower + '/icomoon-bower/style.css',
        dirs.bower + '/ui-select/dist/select.css',
        dirs.bower + '/select2/select2.css',
        dirs.bower + '/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less',
        dirs.content + '/less/_main/*.less'
    ],

    cleanup: [
      dirs.tmp,
      '!' + dirs.dist + '/.gitignore',
      dirs.dist + '/**/*.*'
    ]
};
```

and here are my tasks that I am trying to concat:

```
gulp.task('scripts-dev-vendor', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.vendor)
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulpVendor('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dist));
});


gulp.task('scripts-prod-vendor', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.vendor)
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulpVendor('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dist))
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {  path.basename += '.min'; }))
        .pipe(uglify({ 
            preserveComments: 'some',
            outSourceMap: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dist));
});
```

here is the output when I run that particular task:

```
[15:59:43] Starting 'scripts-dev-vendor'...
[15:59:43] Starting 'widgets-templates'...
[15:59:43] Starting 'compile-modules-templates'...
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: 0 items
[15:59:43] Finished 'widgets-templates' after 72 ms
[15:59:43] Starting 'widgets'...
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\widgets\table\table.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: .tmp\widgets-templates.tpl.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: 2 items
[15:59:43] Finished 'widgets' after 38 ms
[15:59:43] Finished 'compile-modules-templates' after 158 ms
[15:59:43] Starting 'compile-templates'...
[15:59:43] Finished 'compile-templates' after 6.47 ms
[15:59:43] Starting 'scripts-dev-app'...
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: .tmp\widgets.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\app.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: .tmp\modules-templates.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\common\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\config\api-config.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\config\global-const.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\interceptors\auth.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\interceptors\error.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\thirdparty\constellation.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\thirdparty\ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\account\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\dashboard\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\environment\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\layout\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\module.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\api\account.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\api\dashboard.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\api\device.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\api\metrics.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\api\pathfinder.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\auth.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\cachedCollection.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\helpers.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\modal.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\responseFormator.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\spinner.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\services\common\splash.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\common\directives\hcChart\directive.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\common\directives\jqDatepicker\directive.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\common\directives\page-spinner\directive.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\common\directives\resize\directive.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\account\controllers\account.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\account\controllers\login.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\dashboard\dashboard\controllers\dashboard.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\environment\devices\controllers\device.view.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\environment\devices\controllers\devices.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\layout\header\controllers\header.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\layout\layout\controllers\root.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\layout\second-sidebar\controllers\second-sidebar.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\layout\sidebar\controllers\sidebar.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\modals\confirmation\controllers\modal.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\modals\timerange\controllers\modal.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\DeviceTypes\controllers\deviceType.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\DeviceTypes\controllers\deviceTypes.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\users\controllers\companies.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\users\controllers\company.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\settings\users\controllers\user.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\modals\device\add\controllers\modal.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: Content\app\modules\modals\device\edit\controllers\modal.controller.js
[15:59:43] gulp-debug: 50 items
[15:59:43] Finished 'scripts-dev-app' after 147 ms
Process terminated with code 0.
```

This is how I start my scripts-dev-vendor task

```
    // composite tasks
gulp.task('scripts-dev',  ['scripts-dev-vendor', 'scripts-dev-app']);
gulp.task('scripts-prod',  ['scripts-prod-vendor', 'scripts-prod-app']);
gulp.task('common-static', ['assets']);

// build task
gulp.task('build', ['cleanup'], function () {
    gulp.start('common-static', 'lint', 'scripts-prod', 'css-prod');
});

gulp.task('dev', ['cleanup'], function () {
    gulp.start('common-static', 'lint', 'scripts-dev', 'css-dev'); 
});
```

When I run scripts-dev-vendor task on it's own it comes up with an error saying:

```
[10:59:50] Task 'scripts-dev:scripts-dev-vendor' is not in your gulpfile
[10:59:50] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Comment: Do you get some error or what is the end result of this task?

Comment: No I did not get any errors looking at the console.  Do you want me to put the console log up as well?

Comment: Yes, it could be helpful. Why do you have `.pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dist))` twice?

Comment: I have attached the console log for when I run the task

Comment: Your `scripts-dev-vendor` task starts but never finishes. How is it invoked?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I have updated my post

Comment: @TheFallen  I have found an error in my gulp file but not sure how to rectify this

Comment: What is the exact command that you tun to get this error?

Comment: @TheFallen I went into vs task runner explorer and ran this task scripts-dev-vendor